# 'WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine' is not registered exception

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ocr

I have an app that uses OcrEngine. Yesterday it worked fine, but today, after adding and configuring an adMediator control, the line

```
ocrEngine = new OcrEngine(OcrLanguage.English);
```

throws me a runtime exception:

> Requested Windows Runtime type 'WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine' is
>   not registered.

I reinstalled OcrEngine with nuget, but it isn't working yet.

**Edit:**

The problem seems to be related with the

> Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Display DLL

because if I add an `AdControl` to an app that is working fine, the exception appears.

Comment: Was the NuGet package updated since you last used it?

Comment: The runtime version is the same "WindowsRuntime 1.3" I uninstalled it and instaled it again with nuget without success.

Comment: Can you find a stock example of `OcrEngine`, and see if that works - to try and rule out the package or Visual Studio?

Comment: If I turn back to a point where admediator is not present it works again.